# is there fixed character that used in the exponential function?

Tags: plot, graph, conditional-statements, sympy, exponential

I want to solve this problem using the sympy.

[a copper ball heated to 100 degrees was placed in water at 30 degrees, and after 3 minute, the temperature of the copper ball dropped to 70 degrees. Find the time it takes for the temperature of the copper ball to drop to 31 degrees. According to the experiment, the temperature change rate of the copper ball is proportional to the difference between the temperature and the ambient temperature.]

So, I built this equation and conditions.

[T : the temperature of the ball // t : time [m] // a : proportional constant]
[dT/dt = -a(T-30), T(0)=100, T(3)=70]

And my code is as follows...

```
T = symbols('T', cls=Function)
t = symbols('t')
a = symbols('a')
deqn = Eq(T(t).diff(t), -a*(T(t)-30))
dsolve(deqn) # general solution
```

The general solution of the above is : ()=1−+30

```
dsolve(deqn, ics={T(0):100}) #particular solution by boundary condition
```

And the particular solution is : ()=30+70−

Now, I think I need to using this equation to find the value of 'a' due to T(3)=70.

```
C = Eq(30+70*exp(-a*t),30)
solve(C)
```

But, the error occurs...

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [122], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 C = Eq(30+70*exp(-a*t),30)
      2 solve(C)

TypeError: bad operand type for unary -: 'list'
```

I don't know what the problem is...

is there a set character when using 'exp'?

please..help...me....

Comment: The error indicates that `a` is a list. You have assigned to it somewhere.

Comment: examine `a*t`.  Basic debugging is test the pieces of the problem line.

Answer (score 0):

You might have an old version of sympy that used to return `symbols` in a list. Check `type(a) is list`. If it is True, then use a newer version of SymPy, or use `Symbol` to create a single symbol, or unpack the list `a = symbols('a')[0]`.

If that is not the issue, make sure to put 31 as the 2nd arg for `C` (per problem description, else the Eq will be False). And then use `solve(C, t)` or else it might try solve for `a`.